# How to run .sql script file in c++?

Tags: c++, mysql, database

I want to execute a script file of mysql in my code, written in c++. How i can do it ?

Comment: One does not simply execute a mysql script in c++

Comment: jk :D try this -> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-query.html

Answer (score 5):

You can always use the `system` function to call the `mysql` program to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want the optimal solution, simply iterate over each line (your SQL file shall have only ONE command for each line) using the standard C++ file handlings.

You simply pass each line to the MySQL library calls. This is what I do for my SQLite initialization scripts.

You can even add a very minimal comment support (like `--`) and skip any line starting with those characters.